Stack overflow with std::bitset
I have an example of some code that always causes a stack overflow on my machine. Oddly enough, this seems to work fine on Compiler Explorer. I am using Debian 12.
#include <bitset>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T IndexFromXY(T x, T y, T width) {
    return x + (y * width);
}

template<size_t _width, size_t _height>
struct ExploredMap {
    static const size_t width = _width;
    static const size_t height = _height;
    //std::bitset<width * height> storage;
    std::array<bool, width * height> storage;

    const bool get(size_t x, size_t y) const {
        return storage[IndexFromXY(x, y, width)];
    }

    void set(size_t x, size_t y, bool val) {
        storage[IndexFromXY(x, y, width)] = val;
    }

    ExploredMap* operator->() {
        return this;
    }
};

#define EXPECT_EQ(x, y) if (!(x == y)) throw std::runtime_error("no")

const size_t dim = 10000;
using Map = ExploredMap<dim, dim>;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "size of map: " << sizeof(Map) << std::endl;
    Map map;
    for (size_t y = 0; y < Map::height; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < Map::width; x++) {
            map->set(x, y, true);
            EXPECT_EQ(map->get(x, y), true);

            map->set(x, y, false);
            EXPECT_EQ(map->get(x, y), false);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}

When I run it under valgrind I get the following output...
~/C/BitsetMCVE $ valgrind ./prog 
==166101== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==166101== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==166101== Using Valgrind-3.22.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==166101== Command: ./prog
==166101== 
==166101== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x1ffefffed0 --> 0x1ff90a1d90
==166101==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=100000064 or greater
==166101== Invalid write of size 8
==166101==    at 0x109237: main (in /home/david/C/BitsetMCVE/prog)
==166101==  Address 0x1ff90a1d88 is on thread 1's stack
==166101== 
==166101== 
==166101== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==166101==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FF90A1D88
==166101==    at 0x109237: main (in /home/david/C/BitsetMCVE/prog)
==166101==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==166101==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==166101==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==166101==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==166101==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==166101== 
==166101== HEAP SUMMARY:
==166101==     in use at exit: 73,728 bytes in 1 blocks
==166101==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 73,728 bytes allocated
==166101== 
==166101== LEAK SUMMARY:
==166101==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==166101==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==166101==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==166101==    still reachable: 73,728 bytes in 1 blocks
==166101==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==166101== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==166101== 
==166101== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==166101== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
~/C/BitsetMCVE $ 

And when I run with -fsanitize=address...
~/C/BitsetMCVE $ clang++ main.cpp -o prog -fsanitize=address && ./prog 
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==166310==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7fff83051f68 (pc 0x55f718726603 bp 0x7fff88fb0210 sp 0x7fff83051f40 T0)
    #0 0x55f718726603 in main (/home/david/C/BitsetMCVE/prog+0xe1603) (BuildId: c45915efbbbb5e1739feda4db8ba057014e3c234)
    #1 0x7f8f46046249 in __libc_start_call_main csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16
    #2 0x7f8f46046304 in __libc_start_main csu/../csu/libc-start.c:360:3
    #3 0x55f7186663d0 in _start (/home/david/C/BitsetMCVE/prog+0x213d0) (BuildId: c45915efbbbb5e1739feda4db8ba057014e3c234)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow (/home/david/C/BitsetMCVE/prog+0xe1603) (BuildId: c45915efbbbb5e1739feda4db8ba057014e3c234) in main
==166310==ABORTING
~/C/BitsetMCVE $ 

Does anyone know how to debug this?

I suspect that the problem is not with bitset... time to get out your debugger! Side note don't do this : ExploredMap* operator->() {  return this;  }.  Just write map.set(x, y, true); ... Why would you even do this?

the operator-> was just to make debugging easier so I didn't have to swap back and forth between . and -> when creating the object in different ways

100000 * 100000 bytes is quite a lot for the stack.

I think I see, your map is just too big to allocate on the stack. Use std::make_unique<Map> to allocate it on the heap

It's 12.5 MB, I thought that was ok. Is that just far too much for the stack?

@DavidCarpenter Yes, it usually is.

Is there a setting for this, or a way I can view how big of a stack object I can get away with on any particular system?

On posix systems you can check with getrlimit to get the processes max stack size but you'd be better off to use a container that does dynamic memory allocation. A unique_ptr<std::array<bool, width * height>> (or bitset) or even std::vector<bool>(width * height) would work.  std::vector<bool> is often specialized to only use 1 bit per bool.

Since dim is 10'000, std::bitset<width * height> or std::array<bool, width * height> request a container with 100'000'000 elements.
Even with the compact way that std::bitset stores eight bits per byte, this requests 12.5 MB, and that is beyond the usual maximum stack size.
See also C/C++ maximum stack size of program on mainstream OSes. Something like 1-8 MiB is the usual default limit.
You could give it static storage duration (which puts all the memory into a static memory section of your program, which can be as large as you want) with
static Map map;

... or allocate it dynamically with
auto map = std::make_unique<Map>();

You can also make storage a type that allocates its memory dynamically, such as std::vector<bool>.
You can also increase the maximum stack size, although the approach isn't portable.
See Change stack size for a C++ application in Linux during compilation with GNU compiler for how.

Sorry for the error, on my local machine I get the error with it just the 10K^2 elements. I copied that code off of compiler explorer where it was working fine with 100K^2

@DavidCarpenter alright, I've adjusted the answer based on that, but it doesn't change much since 12.5 MB is still too much.

One side note: use constexpr for core constant values instead of const.
